# getting 500 internal server error in laravel

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-3

I am new to `laravel`. I am trying to configure `laravel` accoring to tutorial `https://github.com/jasonlewis/laravel-blog/wiki/Creating-a-simple-blog-in-Laravel-3`. I have created `admin` folder but when I am trying to run `http://localhost/blog/admin`, I am getting the following error :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 Server at localhost Port 80
```

while on `localhost/blog`. It is going perfect, what should I do  ?

Comment: This is more than likely to do with your htaccess. Also, as the author of that (incomplete) tutorial, I'd recommend you look elsewhere. The code there is outdated and unfinished. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your document root is pointed at localhost/blog/public/.  If localhost/blog pulls up the Laravel splash screen OR whatever you'd set in the home view, then it's an htaccess issue.  Most likely it's the document root not headed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks to all, I have solved my problem by creating a virtual domain using apache/vhostconf

Comment: Please explain in detail how to solve your problem ,becuase I am getting same problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your folders have `755` permission. I cleared this issue with permission. This is first thing do any others. You can get successful output.

Thanks